# Gradle build finished with 662 warnings(s) in 37s 879ms

Tags: java, android

How do I fix Gradle Warnings on my project ,Android Studio 2.3.3 ?

Gradle build => http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1537380138437.txt
warnings => http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1537374315469.txt

(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFN08.jpg

(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T9CT.jpg

(Thread.java:745)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/70M7T.jpg

Comment: Update your Android Studio

Comment: unfortunately I have updated of 3.1 and 3.4 get more errors !!

Comment: Please add at least some snippets of the linked code here. This also helps other users to find answers to this question via search engines.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to convey textual information. It is more difficult to read and is inaccessible for those with vision deficiencies who rely on text-based assistive technologies such as screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these warnings look like they are related to your strings :

```
warning: string 'DateColor' has no default translation.
```

Do you have more than one `Strings.xml` files in your project? The first thing I would do if it's the case is make sure that all your string resources are present in every `Strings.xml` files.

Comment: dear Michael Lihs

Comment: i am not such a profi i can send all the files by email to you? I can also write in German

Comment: part Schnipsel :warning: string 'reportMessage' has no default translation.
warning: string 'restoreErrorMsg' has no default translation.
warning: string 'restoreOkMsg' has no default translation.
warning: string 'right' has no default translation.
warning: string 'saveFailed' has no default translation.
warning: string 'securitySectionRow' has no default translation.
warning: string 'send_email' has no default translation.
warning: string 'send_message_in_telegram' has no default translation.
warning: string 'setCity' has no default translation.
warning: string 'share'